# Can't login to icloud.com after switching back region from China mainland to USA

Tags: icloud

I'm getting this

> **Connection Error**
>
> iCloud encountered an error while trying to connect to the server.

error message on all devices and network environment, after I've changed back my region from China mainland to the US (I was in China for a while and switched my app store to China).

Have contacted Apple support but they are of no help. Has anyone had the same issue? My hunch is that it has something to do with the different icloud operator GCBD in China, and it might need to transfer the data from GCBD to the US servers under the hood?